# Different pids when starting process from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I'm writing `init.d` script and I faced some issue with saving forked process pid.

Here is my init script piece:

```
sudo -u $USER nohup -- nice -n "0" java Test >> /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
NEWPID="$!"
echo $NEWPID
```

But when I run this script I have the following pid being printed

```
$./scr.sh
4595
```

But

```
$ps  | grep java
 4596 pts/23   00:00:01 java
```

As you can see the `pid`s are different (`4596` and `4595`). But if tried to write the following:

```
java Test &
NEWPID="$!"
echo $NEWPID
```

I got the correct result:

```
$./scr.sh
4653
$ps  | grep java
 4653 pts/23   00:00:03 java
```

What's wrong with the first one?

Comment: sudo lanch a shell and after that the process fork again

Comment: you might be getting the PID of the (temporary) `sudo` process...

Comment: No "might" about it; `sudo` is the command that runs in the background, so that's what `$!` reports.

Comment: @chepner So it's a bad practice to use `sudo ...` within init.d script? I have to run init script by the appropriate user?

Comment: @m47730 Can't you suggest a wayt to fix that?

Comment: No, just that `$!` is the wrong process ID. I *think* `nohup` is the reason, as it has to create a new process rather than just `exec`ing `nice`.

Comment: @chepner but without `nohup` I run the risk of getting my application stop in case of logout, right?

Answer (score 3):

In an inefficient world, there would be multiple processes involved:

```
<the shell>   1234
    |
    |
  sudo        4595
    |
    |
  nohup       4596
    |
    |
  nice        4597
    |
    |
  java        4598
```

`$!` only refers to the process starts in the background by the shell itself, which is the process that runs `sudo`. `java`, the process you are interested in, is in process 4598. You'll need to use `ps` (or some other tools) to get that process ID, as the shell won't know it.

---

In the *real* world, there aren't quite so many processes involved, since not every job in the chain above has to fork a new process; some of them can simply use `exec` to replace themselves with the program they run. I *think* that `sudo` and `nice` both do this (`nohup` has to start a new process in a different process group for it to do what it does). So the chain looks more like

```
<the shell>      1234
    |
    |
 sudo/nohup      4595
    |
    |
 nice/java       4596
```

But the end result is the same; the shell doesn't have any way of getting the process ID of the process in which `java` ultimately runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing `$!` from within the same shell you started the background process:

```
NEWPID=$(sudo -u $USER bash -c "nohup -- nice -n 0 java Test >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null & echo $!")
echo $NEWPID
```